# How to count no of row with like command in Codeignighter

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, count

I have tried this code for count rows

```
$count = $this->db->query("select count(*) from cgdict where cg like '%".$search_data."%'");

echo $count;
```

and it gives me an error

```
Object of class CI_DB_mysqli_result could not be converted to string
```

Comment: You want that SQL injection, do you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysqli : mysqli\_result could not be converted to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573134/mysqli-mysqli-result-could-not-be-converted-to-string)

Comment: you should use `$row = $this->db->query(...)->row()` anf then `$count=$row->count` you are directly assigning a result object to a field

Comment: Your query is ok. But `echo $count` is wrong. Because echo prints out a string. But `$count` is not a string. Its object.try to use print_r or var_dump to see what is $count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `num_rows()` to count function, because `$count` is an array (if not null):

```
$query = $this->db->query("select * from cgdict where cg like '%".$search_data."%'");
$result = $query->result_array()
$num= $result ->num_rows();
echo $num;
```

Or

```
$query = $this->db->query("select count(*) as TotCount from cgdict where cg like '%".$search_data."%'");
$result = $query->result_array()

echo count($result[0]['TotCount']);
```

### Security note

Before sending `$search_data` direct to SQL query, make sure you use [`$this->input->post`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html) to catch and clean from SQL injection.

Comment: I edit this by         $query = $this->db->query("select * from cgdict where cg like '%".$search_data."%'");
$num= $result ->num_rows();
echo $num;

Comment: $result = $query->result_array(); not required there................... its working perfectly now... thanks....

Comment: echo count($result[0]['TotCount']); this one was given 1 in every run... so i used first one.